# PySpark - Add Row Number After Using Explode Function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, explode, row-number

I'm doing an nlp project and have reviews that contain multiple sentences. I am using the spark-nlp package that outputs one column containing a list of the sentences in each review. I am using explode to create a row for each sentence but I want to add numbering so I know which sentence was 1st, 2nd, etc. I don't know how to use row_number() because I don't really have anything to orderBy.

Here's what my data looks like:

```
REVIEW_ID REVIEW_COMMENTS     SENTENCES_LIST           
    1     Hi. Sent1. Sent2.   [Hi., Sent1., Sent2.]   
    2     Yeah. Ok.           [Yeah., Ok.]
```

Here's what I want it to look like:

```
REVIEW_ID REVIEW_COMMENTS     SENTENCES_LIST           SENTENCE  SENT_NUMBER
    1     Hi. Sent1. Sent2.   [Hi., Sent1., Sent2.]    Hi.       1
    1     Hi. Sent1. Sent2.   [Hi., Sent1., Sent2.]    Sent1.    2
    1     Hi. Sent1. Sent2.   [Hi., Sent1., Sent2.]    Sent2.    3
    2     Yeah. Ok.           [Yeah., Ok.]             Yeah.     1
    2     Yeah. Ok.           [Yeah., Ok.]             Ok.       2
```

I'm using the code below and not sure how to use row_number() because I don't have a column to use as the "orderBy" except for it's placement in the SENTENCES_LIST.

```
df2 = df.withColumn('SENTENCE', F.explode('SENTENCES_LIST'))
df3 = df2.withColumn('SENT_NUMBER',row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('REVIEW_ID').orderBy('????')))
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking for [`pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.posexplode)? Try: `df2 = df.withColumn('SENTENCE', F.posexplode('SENTENCES_LIST').alias("SENT_NUMBER", "SENT_NUMBER"))`

Comment: @pault 'The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns output by the UDTF expected 2 aliases but got SENTENCE ;'

Comment: This works though `df.select('*', F.posexplode('SENTENCES_LIST').alias('SENT_NUMBER', 'SENTENCE'))`

Answer (score 5):

For **`Spark2.4+`**, you can use **`explode`** with higher order function **`transform.`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("list", F.explode(F.expr("""transform(SENTENCES_LIST,(x,i)-> struct(x as SENTENCE,(i+1) as SENT_NUMBER))""")))\
  .select("*", "list.*").show()

#+---------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
#|REVIEW_ID|  REVIEW_COMMENTS|      SENTENCES_LIST|       list|SENTENCE|SENT_NUMBER|
#+---------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
#|        1|Hi. Sent1. Sent2.|[Hi., Sent1., Sen...|   [Hi., 1]|     Hi.|          1|
#|        1|Hi. Sent1. Sent2.|[Hi., Sent1., Sen...|[Sent1., 2]|  Sent1.|          2|
#|        1|Hi. Sent1. Sent2.|[Hi., Sent1., Sen...|[Sent2., 3]|  Sent2.|          3|
#|        2|        Yeah. Ok.|        [Yeah., Ok.]| [Yeah., 1]|   Yeah.|          1|
#|        2|        Yeah. Ok.|        [Yeah., Ok.]|   [Ok., 2]|     Ok.|          2|
#+---------+-----------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, your code worked but I ended up using: `df.select('*', F.posexplode('SENTENCES_LIST').alias('SENT_NUMBER', 'SENTENCE'))` which was more appropriate

Comment: @user3242036 true that is more appropriate

Comment: In retrospect this is overkill in comparison to posexplode. Thanks @pault